# How to substitute a string even it contains regex meta characters using Shell or Perl?

Tags: regex, perl, sed

I want to substitue a word which maybe contains regex meta characters to another word, for example, substitue the `.Precilla123` as `.Precill`, I try to use below solution:

```
sed 's/.Precilla123/.Precill/g'
```

but it will change below line

```
"Precilla123";"aaaa aaa";"bbb bbb"
```

to

```
.Precill";"aaaa aaa";"bbb bbb"
```

This side effect is not I wanted. So I try to use:

```
perl -pe 's/\Q.Precilla123\E/.Precill/g'
```

The above solution can disable interpreted regex meta characters, it will not have the side effect.
Unfortunately, if the word contains `$` or `@`, this solution still cannot work, because Perl keep `$` and `@` as variable prefix.

Can anybody help this? Many thanks.

**Please note that the word I want to substitute is NOT hard coded, it comes from a input file, you can consider it as variable.**

Comment: `abc$efg` => `abcdefg`

Comment: Why don't you consider escaping the meta character or putting them inside a character class?

Comment: Are you generating a script to run scripts? that sound like a bad idea. Could you show how you are generating the "intermediate" file? Also, have a look at `quotemeta`, maybe it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Unfortunately, if the word contains `$` or `@`, this solution still cannot work, because Perl keep `$` and `@` as variable prefix.

This is not true.

If the value that you want to replace is in a Perl variable, then [`quotemeta`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) will work on the variable's contents just fine, including the characters `$` and `@`:

```
echo 'pre$foo to .$foobar' | perl -pe 'my $from = q{.$foo}; s/\Q$from\E/.to/g'
```

Outputs:

```
pre$foo to .tobar
```

If the words that you want to replace are in an external file, then simply load that data in a BEGIN block before composing your regular expressions for replacement.

Comment: Your answer is correct and very professional. Thnaks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/\.Precilla123/.Precill/g'
```

Escape the meta character with `\`.

Be carrefull, mleta charactere are not the same for search pattern that are mainly regex `[]{}()\.*+^$` where replacement is limited to `&\^$` (+ the separator that depend of your first char after the `s` in both pattern)